# Ошибка AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute

Tags: ansible

Всем привет. Натолкнулся на любопытную проблему.

Входные данные (ansible 2.2):

1. Inventory

```
[api]
api01.domain.tld max_fails=12 fail_timeout=70 
api02.domain.tld max_fails=13 fail_timeout=70 
api03.domain.tld max_fails=12 fail_timeout=70 
api04.domain.tld max_fails=12 fail_timeout=70
```

2. Шаблон для описания nginx upstreams (важен второй цикл):

```
{% for upstream1 in nginx_upstreams1.iteritems() %}
upstream {{ upstream1[0] }} {
{% for item in upstream1[1] %}
  {{ item }};
{% endfor %}
{% for host in groups[upstream1[0]] %}
  # {{ host }}
  server {{ hostvars[host].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }} ;
  {{ hostvars[host].max_fails }}
{% endfor %}
}
{% endfor %}
max_fails {{ hostvars['api01.domain.tld'].max_fails }}
max_fails {{ hostvars['api02.domain.tld'].max_fails }}
```

3. В результате я получаю, что

а) код `- {{ hostvars[host].max_fails }}` - выдает `"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'max_fails'"`

б) когда я указываю в hostvars имя хоста руками все отрабатывает корректно (  `max_fails {{ hostvars['api01.domain.tld'].max_fails }}` )

в) когда я смотрю дебажный вывод ad-hoc через `-m debug`, или вывожу `hostvars[host]` в отрендеренный шаблон — `max_fails` там присутствует.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Поправил заголовок для лучшей индексации поисковиками.

Answer (score 1):

У меня скорее комментарий "на моей версии ansible всё работает", пишу ответом лишь для того, чтобы листинги были читаемые.

Также хочу чтобы вы сделали полностью воспроизводимый пример, т.к. некоторых переменных не хватает (nginx_upstreams1)  - и мне пришлось их выбросить. Возможно, это повлияло на выполнение скрипта.

Я, кстати, не помню, нет ли какой-то служебной переменной `host` но точно знаю, что я во всех скриптах предпочитаю переменную для обхода называть `item`. Возможно ли, что в 2.2 появилась какая-то новая переменная?

Сам скрипт:

```
- name: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601512/
  hosts: api
  tasks:
    - name: template nginx conf
      template:
        src="test.j2"
        dest="/home/ansible/test.txt"
```

Шаблон:

```
upstream {

{% for host in groups['api'] %}
  # {{ host }}
  server {{ hostvars[host].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }} ;
  {{ hostvars[host].max_fails }}
{% endfor %}
}

max_fails {{ hostvars['api01.domain.tld'].max_fails }}
max_fails {{ hostvars['api02.domain.tld'].max_fails }}
```

Версия ПО:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.1.2.0
  config file = /home/ak/ansible/so/601512/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

PS И даже через переменную работает:

Скрипт:

```
- name: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601512/
  hosts: api
  vars:
    group_name: "api"
  tasks:
    - name: debug group_name
      debug: msg="{{ group_name }}"
    - name: template nginx conf
      template:
        src="test.j2"
        dest="/home/ansible/test.txt"
```

Шаблон:

```
upstream {

{% for host in groups['api'] %}
  # {{ host }}
  server {{ hostvars[host].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }} ;
  {{ hostvars[host].max_fails }}
{% endfor %}

{% for host in groups[group_name] %}
  # {{ host }}
  server {{ hostvars[host].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }} ;
  {{ hostvars[host].max_fails }}
{% endfor %}
}

max_fails {{ hostvars['api01.domain.tld'].max_fails }}
max_fails {{ hostvars['api02.domain.tld'].max_fails }}
```

PPS Аналогично, нет проблем и вокруг `play_hosts` сделать обход: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005760/ansible-play-hosts-template-loop